# Plot alphabetical labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm trying to get alphabetical labels (a, b, c, d, ...) superimposed on to a series of *Mathematica* plots to put into a $\LaTeX$ document. Ideally, what I'd like to do is to add a label to the first graph with "drawing tools" so I can set the size and position by hand. Then somehow to access the size, position, etc. of this inset graphic so I can then automatically add the labels for the other graphs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I mean, have you some code to show your try?

Answer (score 2):

you might find this useful:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{Plot[Sin[y], {y, 0, 4}], 
   Graphics[Inset[Text["(A)"], Scaled[{x, y}]]]}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
  1},
 LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

after using `Manipulate` to set the position, `{x,y}` will be set, so additional plots will have their label in the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> Inset[Text[Style["(a)", 20, Black, 15]], Scaled[{0.1, 0.9}]]];

plot2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> Inset[Text[Style["(b)", 20, Black, 15]], Scaled[{0.1, 0.1}]]];

GraphicsColumn[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but do you know if there's a way to make those insets selectable?